Docker build through github workflow fails while trying to pass multiple build args
I'm trying to deploy a flask app to gcp using docker and github workflows. I have added few variables and secrets in github which i'm trying to pass as build args through my workflow yaml file (which I'm later using in my code using os.getenv()
That's giving me an error -

Error with the json secret

run docker buildx build --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="<url>" --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="<login_url>" --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="<db_url>" --build-arg GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR="***
docker buildx build --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="<url>" --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="<login_url>" --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="<db_url>" --build-arg GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR="***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
    ***
  ***
  " -t gcr.io/<pid>/profile-extractor .
  docker push gcr.io/<pid>/profile-extractor
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
  
ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker buildx build --help'.

Usage:  docker buildx build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

This is what my deploy.yml and dockerfile look like -
deploy.yml
name: Deploy to Cloud Run

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Cloud SDK
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
      with:
        version: 'latest'
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_EXTRACTOR }}

    - name: Configure Docker
      run: gcloud auth configure-docker

    - name: Build and push Docker image
      env:
        MGL_BASE_URL: ${{ vars.MGL_BASE_URL }}
        MGL_LOGIN_URL: ${{ vars.MGL_LOGIN_URL }}
        FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: ${{ vars.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}
        GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR }}
      run: |
        docker build \
                     -t gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor . \
                     --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="${{ vars.MGL_BASE_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="${{ vars.MGL_LOGIN_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="${{ vars.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR="${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR }}"
        docker push gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor

    - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
      run: |
        gcloud run deploy profile-extractor --image gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor --platform managed --region asia-south2 --allow-unauthenticated --project ${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}

Dockerfile
# Use the official Python image from the Docker Hub
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Pass environment variables as build arguments
ARG MGL_BASE_URL
ARG MGL_LOGIN_URL
ARG FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
ARG GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR

# Set environment variables in the container
ENV MGL_BASE_URL=$MGL_BASE_URL
ENV MGL_LOGIN_URL=$MGL_LOGIN_URL
ENV FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=$FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
ENV GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR=$GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR

# Set environment variables
ENV PORT=8080

# Command to run the application
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "app:app"]

I tried to remove this secret
--build-arg GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR="${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR }}"

since this is added as json so i thought multiline secret could be causing an issue since other variables are just one line strings. But it still failed with the same error.

Error without the json secret

run docker buildx build --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="<url>" --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="<login_url>" --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="<db_url>"
docker buildx build --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="<url>" --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="<login_url>" --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="<db_url>" -t gcr.io/<pid>/profile-extractor .
      docker push gcr.io/<pid>/profile-extractor
      shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
      
    ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
    See 'docker buildx build --help'.
    
    Usage:  docker buildx build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -


Your error message tries to end the build command on FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL, while your yaml has GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR. Removing that line will change the issue encountered. Please either show the failure for the complete file, or update the yaml to match the error.

Added both errors, error with the given yaml file and the one with the GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR removed

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the images with plain text?

The error text provided here is inaccurate. It is showing docker buildx build in the run when you were only executing docker build (in this case, programmatically they are the same, but evidence that we are not looking at the original values). Also, as my answer explains, things like the trailing \ and linefeeds are a very important detail in this question. Please properly copy and paste the text into your question without making assumptions about what is important.

There's two questions here, and the second is easier to answer. When this command was changed from:
        docker build \
                     -t gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor . \
                     --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="${{ vars.MGL_BASE_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="${{ vars.MGL_LOGIN_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="${{ vars.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR="${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR }}"
        docker push gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor

to remove the last build arg like:
        docker build \
                     -t gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor . \
                     --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL="${{ vars.MGL_BASE_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL="${{ vars.MGL_LOGIN_URL }}" \
                     --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="${{ vars.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}" \
        docker push gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor

You left in the \ on the previous line, so that the docker push command was being passed as addition arguments to the docker build command. Remove the backslash to fix that.
The first question, why doesn't the build arg work, is because you are expanding the shell variables in GHA before running the command rather than using the provided environment variables. When GHA expands the values passed to the shell, the content of those variables is interpreted by the shell. If instead the variable is only accessed by the environment variable, the shell expands the environment variable, but doesn't then interpret the content of the expanded value. In this case, you already passed the variables as environment variables that match the build arg names, so you can skip the part where you have GHA inline those values, and even skip the shell environment variable expansion with:
    - name: Build and push Docker image
      env:
        MGL_BASE_URL: ${{ vars.MGL_BASE_URL }}
        MGL_LOGIN_URL: ${{ vars.MGL_LOGIN_URL }}
        FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: ${{ vars.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}
        GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR }}
      run: |
        docker build \
                     -t gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor . \
                     --build-arg MGL_BASE_URL \
                     --build-arg MGL_LOGIN_URL \
                     --build-arg FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL \
                     --build-arg GCP_SA_KEY_PRF_SELECTOR
        docker push gcr.io/${{ vars.PRF_EXTRACTOR_GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/profile-extractor

And if the variable name was different, you could have expanded it in the shell with --build-arg SOME_ARG_NAME="${SOME_ENV_VAR_NAME}".

I changed it to use the env var names instead of expanding the GHA and it does work now.
Just wondering why it would not otherwise, because even though i'm expanding the GHA shouldn't expanding it again work as well?

When GHA expands the variables, it does so in what is parsed by the shell. If the variable contained a " or any other special characters, that would do the same as if you typed it. But if the shell expands the variables, then the content of that variable isn't parsed by the shell.
